# Installed Banana and now the Solr HTTP api stopped working

Tags: solr, lucene, banana

Im very new to Solr (4.10) and Banana. Here is my issue:

- I setup suggestions with multiple dictionaries in the solrconfig.xml file and got them working great in Solr 4.10!
- I use a query like this query to get them: `http://0.0.0.0:8983/solr/coll1/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=store_primary&suggest.dictionary=stores_assoc&&suggest.dictionary=store_all&wt=json&suggest.q=foobar&suggest.build=true`
- then I installed banana and it works well but...
- that query above now returns `HTTP ERROR 404, Problem accessing /solr/coll1/suggest. Reason: Not Found`
- I did make sure to create a new non-time series dash and that is where the http errors below occur

Here is the full error message:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /solr/coll1/suggest. Reason:
Not Found
```

I also tried with the default collection1 with sample data:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /solr/collection1/select. Reason:
Not Found
```

Why can I no longer query the Solr instance behind the banana install? What am I missing? I made sure to populate `coll1` with some sample data as well

Comment: Can you still get a response with a standard query on another collection (without loading dictionary) ? How do you run Banana ? is it a solr web-app, a WAR file or does it run on a web server ? In the latter case you probably setup a proxy (that could cause the issue). Any additional config or information on this would help.

Comment: I cannot get a repsonse on a standard query from another collection. I even tried a vanilla install of Solr using the collection1, which I added 3 records to, and still the same result.

Comment: Ok. Is there a proxy configuration involved ?

Comment: No proxy whatsoever

Comment: There is a `.` within the `404` error message after `suggest`. Either this is a typo by you within the question (good) or within your configuration (bad). Because a typo within your config would lead to a `404`.

Comment: I updated the my question with the full error message. thanks

Comment: So .. what about *How do you run Banana ? is it a solr web-app, a WAR file or does it run on a web server ? Any additional config or information on this would help.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dropping banana in the `apache-tomcat-9.0.27/webapps/` folder instead of inside the Solr webapps directory as described here (https://github.com/lucidworks/banana) and it works now